# Como fazer o gitlab ci acessar a instancia do ec2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-aws, gitlab

eu criei um script para fazer o deploy em uma instancia do ec2. A ideia é entrar no terminal da instancia, rodar um git pull e reiniciar o pm2. Porém quando vou tentar acessar o ec2 aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. 
Host key verification failed.
```

Meu ci yml está assim:

```
make_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add bash
    - apk add git
    - apk add openssh
    - bash scripts/deploy.sh
    - echo "Deploy succeeded!"
  only:
    - master
```

e este é meu script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=gitlab+deploy-token-44444
pass=passwordpass
gitlab="https://"$user":"$pass"@gitlab.com/repo/project.git"

ssh-keygen -R 50-200-50-15

chmod 600 key.pem

ssh -tt -i key.pem ubuntu@ec2-50-200-50-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com << 'ENDSSH'

pm2 delete .
rm -rf project
git clone $gitlab
cd /project
npm i 
npm start

ENDSSH

exit
```

Parece que ele não consegue entrar no terminal do ec2 para rodar esses comandos, pois fora a parte de acessar o terminal da instancia tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Obrigado!

Comment: já conseguiu resolver amigo? caso não, posso tentar te ajudar...

Comment: Não, acabei deixando manual. Acesso o ec2 e la eu dou um pull e restarto o pm2 :(